# How to fix Error: Duplicate resources for global_tracker.xml when adding Google Analytics?

Tags: android, android-resources, google-analytics-firebase, google-play-services

I'm trying to implement Google Analytics in my App , but when compiling I get the following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>   [xml/global_tracker]
>   C:\Users\Carlos\AndroidStudioProjects\Capstone\SP\Stocks Panel
>   Lite\app\src\main\res\xml\global_tracker.xml  [xml/global_tracker]
>   C:\Users\Carlos\AndroidStudioProjects\Capstone\SP\Stocks Panel
>   Lite\app\build\generated\res\google-services\debug\xml\global_tracker.xml:
>   Error: Duplicate resources

I've tried to run clean project, but I get the same error. I also get the same error if I remove app/build.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.carlos.capstone"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:logging-interceptor:2.6.0'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.1.6'
    compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:2.0.4'
    compile 'com.crazyhitty.chdev.ks:rss-manager:0.21'
    compile 'com.github.frankiesardo:linearlistview:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-urlconnection:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:23.0.0+'
    compile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.3.1'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1'
    compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.14'
    compile 'net.sf.supercsv:super-csv:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'

}
```

Comment: show your `build-gradle`

Comment: okay . for test case use `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'` no need `services-analytics:8.3.0`

Comment: any crash if comment out `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` ?? you can set this bottom line of your configuration

Comment: I've implemented the solution given by Levon? Do you want me to put again global_tracker.xml and try it?

Comment: when using compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0' without apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' i get the following error  building: * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzmx.class

Comment: this error dissapears when i change from compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0' to 7.3.0

Comment: comment `multiDexEnabled true`

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
commenting multiDexEnabled:
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This happens when you place a `global_tracker.xml` in your resources xml folder and in addition to that add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` in your `build.gradle` file. That is mixing the old way of implementing the tracker with the new way of doing things. The solution would be to simply remove the `global_tracker.xml` from your xml folder, as the google-services plugin will automatically add all the required data from the `google-services.json` configuration file when building your app.

Also, it's advisable to place the `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` line at the bottom of your `build.gradle` after the dependencies section. It's strange, but having it at the top causes errors in some configurations.

In addition, you might see **error: cannot find symbol variable global_tracker** when trying to build your project, especially if you are converting an older project, and downloaded your `google-services.json` from your Firebase console while still using it with the older Google Analytics. In that case, open the newly added `google-services.json` and find "analytics_service" in the "services" object. You will need to add the following:

```
"analytics_property": {
    "tracking_id": "<your tracking id>"
```

so the entire section looks like this (place your own UA-XXXXXXXX-X tracking ID there):

```
"analytics_service": {
  "status": 2,
  "analytics_property": {
      "tracking_id": "UA-12345678-9"
  }
},
```

After that make sure to Clean your project and re-sync Gradle before you rebuild. Hope that helps.

Comment: The error dissapeared, but the problem is that Analytics is not showing current User. I have done another little app to test Analytics with this site https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#set-up-your-project and this one https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/04/working-with-google-analytics-api-v4-for-android.html all worked perfectly(including global_tracker.xml). It is strange

Comment: Showing current user is a different unrelated issue. If my answer helped you with your original question, please mark it as accepted answer. Then post a different question specifically about current user issue. Thanks.

Comment: don't we need the tracker object ?
  Tracker mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();

Comment: @iappmaker Yes, you still need the Tracker object in your code, but the question here was about the configuration of the project, rather than how to implement it in code.

Comment: How can we do this and still apply custom settings? Is there an alternative solution that involves 'fixing' the autogeneration of a global_tracker.xml?

Comment: The problem dissapear but now I'm getting: "You have wrong OAuth2 related configurations, please check. Detailed error: INVALID_AUDIENCE"

Comment: @DiegoVenâncio Please start a new post about your OAuth2 error, as it's not related to what the OP asked. Thanks!